# Decompose input space of non-injective function into a collection of contours?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Consider a non-injective function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. What conditions on $f$ guarantee that the input space can be written as a collection of contours of $f$?
$$
\mathbb{R}^n = \bigcup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^m} f^{-1}(\{y\})
$$
My guess is that this is true for any smooth $f$, but perhaps this is a strong condition and it is possible to relax it.

###### Attempted Solution

$$
\implies
$$
Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f^{-1}(\{f(x)\}) = \{z\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\,f(z) = f(x)\}$. In particular $x\in f^{-1}(\{x\})$ so $\mathbb{R}^n\subseteq \bigcup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^m} f^{-1}(\{y\})$.
$$
\impliedby
$$
Let $z\in \bigcup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^m} f^{-1}(\{y\})$. Then necessarily $z\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$ for some $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$. By definition this means $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: It is always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always true for any function $f: A \to B$. Indeed for all $a \in A$
$$a \in f^{-1}(f(a)) \subseteq \bigcup_{y \in B} f^{-1}(y)$$
Hence $$A \subseteq \bigcup_{y \in B} f^{-1}(y)$$
and the opposite inclusion is trivial.

Comment: I suppose this is true for any partition of $B$ right?

Comment: That is if $B_1, B_2, \ldots$ is a partition of $B$ (i.e. they are mutually disjoint and their union gives $B$) then 
$$
A = \bigcup_i f^{-1}(B_i)
$$

Comment: Yes, it is true for any partion of $B$